# How can I parse an "@odata.nextLink" to an apex class?

Tags: apex, json, parser

My json response from Azure includes an attribute that's "@odata.nextlink: [url]". 
In my parser class how can I get this url value? I can't declare it as something like Public String @odata.nextLink or Public String odata.nextlink because it doesn't like the special character or path-like syntax with the '.'

Can anyone help?
TIA!

Comment: Have the same issue. I tried playing around a bit with the URL like $format=JSON and other stuff but the result was always the same.

Comment: Thanks! Instead of parsing to a class, I ended up converting it to a map instead and that worked. :)